# Initializing my variable doesn't works by first click, but by second click it works

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, ajax, jpa

if I enter an article number, for example 100100 and then click on the button, my array parent is empty, although it actually has to be overwritten by the method called. however, when I click the button a second time, the array is no longer empty. Why is that? I want my array to be overwritten after the first click.

my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    getAlleArtikelstücklisten();
})

function getAlleArtikelstücklisten(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/orderLists/open",
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: handleData
      });
}
function handleData(data){
    alleArtikelstücklisten=data;
    console.log(alleArtikelstücklisten);
}
```

Comment: prefer english in you code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because the `console.log` gets called before the `getParent()` function finishes. It is returning the value from the first click/call  when you click it the second time.

You can pass async: false, to fix it.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/m_stücklistenelement/selectByArtikelnummerStückliste?artikelnummerStückliste="+artikelnmr,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: handleDataParent,
        async: false
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

could you have forgotten function parentheses in the 'success' calls?

```
success: handleData(data)
```

Comment: I don't think that this is the problem, because by ```getAllArtikelstücklisten()```  it works